# NextJS on Vercel, HTTP proxy not working (405 Method not allowed)

Tags: http, next.js, proxy, vercel, http-status-code-405

I followed [this](https://maxschmitt.me/posts/next-js-api-proxy) to proxy all requests from my NextJS app to a separate backend hosted at a **different** URL

Env vars are:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=/api
API_URL=https://other-host.com/api/v1
```

So, a request from the web app (that reads the URL from `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL` var),

such as `POST /api/user/login { ...payload }`

would be proxied to `https://other-host.com/api/v1/user/login`

**It works on localhost**

But not after deploying to Vercel

Am I missing some config or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Proxy HTTP requests to a different host, in a NextJS app deployed to Vercel